# DateTime with offset Parse in NodaTime

Tags: c#, nodatime

If I have a string like "2020-12-15T12:10:00.202-08:00" how can I parse this into NodaTime.LocalDateTime
or ZonedDateTime directly, rather than doing something like:

LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime.Parse("2020-12-15T12:10:00.202"))

And similarly for the other NodaTime types like LocalDate, Instant etc.

my end goal is to take the offset/timezone and change it to another

Help is appreciated.

I believe I need to work with modifying the pattern:

```
Var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

but I tried to add a z at the end for the timezone and that appears to be incorrect

even saw another post that mentions make it the full 9 digits:

```
static readonly ZonedDateTimePattern ParsePatternA =
            ZonedDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("uuuu'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffffz", DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
```

Comment: https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/userguide/offset-patterns

Answer (score 0):

The value you've got there is logically an `OffsetDateTime`. Fortunately the pattern is simple ISO-8601, so you don't need to create any kind of custom pattern.

I'd strongly advise you to parse directly to the type that the value logically represents, *then* perform any conversions if you need to.

```cs
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

string text = "2020-12-15T12:10:00.202-08:00";

OffsetDateTimePattern pattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.ExtendedIso;
ParseResult<OffsetDateTime> parseResult = pattern.Parse(text);
if (parseResult.Success)
{
    OffsetDateTime value = parseResult.Value;
    Console.WriteLine($"Successfully parsed: {value}");
    // If you really need to convert to LocalDateTime...
    LocalDateTime local = value.LocalDateTime;
    Console.WriteLine($"Local value: {local}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Unable to parse value: {parseResult.Exception.Message}");
}
```